# Importing a specific function from a module

Tags: python-2.7, function, import

I have a module called `prog1.py` which contains a function and other statements, like this:

```
def func(a,b,c)
    ...
    ...
    return output
var = input('input')
    ...
```

I'm trying to call just the function `func` from a different module `prog2.py` like this:

```
from prog1 import func

N = input('input2')
for i in range(N)
    func(x,y,z) # with x,y,z already defined
```

So when executing `prog2.py` instead of asking for my `input2`, it asks for my input from `prog1.py`. I can move `from prog1 import func` to my for loop but I don't want it to ask for the other input. Is there a way to call `func` without using whatever else is in `prog1.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top level code of a module is executed upon import and there is no way around this.

If you don't want the line

```
var = input('input')
```

to be executed, remove it, put it in a function or guard it with

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    var = input('input')
```

(usually at the end of the module).